# is two traversal needed for red-black tree

Tags: java, data-structures, red-black-tree

As we know to get a exact binary tree we need at-least two traversals (in-order and pre-order / in-order and post-order) to get back the original tree. But is it mandatory  to have two traversals (in-order and pre-order / in-order and post-order) to get the original tree if the tree is a red-black tree? Thanks.

Comment: I think only inorder is sufficient

Comment: @tejas thanks. Can you vindicate your comment with some link or article if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to show that in-order traversal is not sufficient, by providing a counter-example:

```
     5B
  3R     10B
1B  4B

      3B
    1B   5R
        4B  10B
```

These are both valid red-black trees whose in-order traversal order is (1,3,4,5,10). Thus, it is impossible to reconstruct a red-black tree by only an in-order traversal of its nodes.

Answer (score 1):

For [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-order_traversal#Depth-first), "Either pre-order or post-order paired with in-order is sufficient to describe the tree uniquely, while pre-order with post-order leaves some ambiguity in the tree structure." In particular, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17635555/230513) shows by counter-example that in-order traversal alone is not sufficient, and this [Q&A](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/439) shows that pre-order & post-order together are not sufficient. Because "a red–black tree is a [special type of binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Terminology)," the answer is yes: At least two traversals, one of which is in-order, are required.

Answer (score 1):

No, a pre-order or a post-order traversal is sufficient.

Since the *red-black tree* is a *binary search tree*, the search tree property implies that the in-order traversal is simply the sorted list of all elements, and thus superfluous.